# Laravel 5.3, Class 'App\Models\User' not found

Tags: laravel

I have laravel app.

It works locally, using `php artisan serve` command.

After deployment to remote server it does not work.

Every artisan command returns:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]  
 Class 'App\Models\User' not found
```

Excerpt from `App\Models\User.php` (case-sensitive).

```
<?
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable {
// code here
}
```

composer dump-autoload does not fix it.

.gitignore

```
/vendor
.env
/public/css/
/public/js/
/public/img/
/public/fonts/
/node_modules/
```

composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Seeds\\": "database/seeds/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/Helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Local system: arch linux with php 7.0
Remote system: debian jessie with php 7.0

Comment: Its supposed to be just `App\User`, did you changed it and added the Model folder?

Comment: Yes, I've replaced all links from `App\User` to `App\Models\User`. It works locally, but not on remote server.

Answer (score 3):

Add `use` clause at the top of a controller where you're trying to use the model:

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Alternatively, you can use full namespace:

```
$user = App\Models\User::find(1);
```

Also, make sure `User.php` is in the `app\Models` directory and make sure you've changed model in `config\auth.php` file:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Model\User::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: You did not read the question carefully. The very same code works locally.

Comment: @changer if the very same code works locally, run `php artisan config:clear` command on the server.

Comment: it does not help. EVERY artisan command fails with same error.

Comment: @changer is this a different error or `User` model related? If it's same error, delete `bootstrap/cache/config.php` manually.

Comment: there is not bootstrap/cache/config.php file, only bootstrap/cache/services.php, which I alread tried to remove. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.

In php.ini set `short_open_tag = On` and voila - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the generated cached files, might still be referencing the old namespace.

`rm -r bootrap/cache` should to the trick

Answer (score 0):

I was using `use App\Models\User;` in my controller when I copied my models from root of app folder to Models folder inside app folder.

An additional change was required which was using `namespace App\Models;` Inside my models so now my User model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
```